# Spa panel amperage upgrade

Tags: electrical-panel

I have a 50 amp gfci spa panel need to make it 60 for new spa. Can I just change the breaker or do I have to change the entire box?

Thanks

Comment: It's important to remember that the breaker's whole purpose is to be the weakest link in the electrical system. If you swap it for a higher rating without making any other changes it's possible you have created a dangerous situation where the wiring could melt and/or catch on fire. When upgrading a system it's important you look at *all* the components.

Answer (score 2):

You'll likely also have to increase the size of the conductors feeding the panel, which means pulling new cable/wires.  But nobody can say for sure, without knowing what's there now.

You *may* have to upgrade the panel, but again it depends on what's there now.